# Python selenium - How to repeatedly select buttons on multiple pages - element not visible

Tags: python, selenium

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://wj.qq.com/s/2214142/51db') # survey link

# First page - click "Next" button, it works
NextButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('survey_nextpage') # got to next page
NextButton.click()


# Second page - click one of the scale button between 1-5
answers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('star_item') # it works
answers[4].click() # it works

NextButton.click() # it works


# Third page - click one of the scale button as 2nd page
answers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('star_item') # either with or without this statement, the next line will give error
answers[2].click() # it throws error

NextButton.click()
```

Starting from page 2, each webpage contains a 1-5 scale (5 buttons) with exactly same format. When the code runs till 3nd page, it will give error like this:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

As I already catched the answer options on Page 2, I don't know why it does work for page 3 which has exactly same scale format as Page 2.

How can I repeatedly apply the same method to choose an option to next following 5 pages with the same survey format?

Any suggests will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are 70 elements on the page with class name `star_item`. And when you are trying to click on second page `answers[2].click()` actually it is the third element from the first page, which of course is not visible anymore. So you have to change your selector, or use this solution:

As I see there are 5 elements on every page, so you can deal with your issue like this:

```
add = 0 # value to add
NextButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('survey_nextpage') # got to next page
NextButton.click()


# Second page - click one of the scale button between 1-5
# you don't have to locate this elements on every page, only once
answers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('star_item') # locate all elements 
answers[4 + add].click() # it will peek an item 4 plus add value
add += 5 # increase the value at 5

NextButton.click()


# Third page - click one of the scale button as 2nd page
answers[2 + add].click()
add += 5
NextButton.click()
```

Explanation to the code: if we know that there are 5 elements on every page, and with this locator we are selecting 70 elements, the 70/5 = 14 pages are having this elements. So to be able to click on the right element of 70 on particular page we introduce a variable that counts the pages already done. This variable is `add`. after passing every page it will be increased at 5.

Comment: Andrei, thanks a lot for your quick reply. I just tried it. It seems the last line does not work. It gives error like this: `TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement`     If I change `answers[2]` to 'answers', the error will be like :  `TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 71 were given`   @Andrei Suvorkov

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this as well, wait some minutes. I think I have found the issue

Comment: `element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'option_q-2-h6F2_4')))
element.click()`  If I try this way using each option's ID, it will give TimeoutException.

Comment: I have found the issue. Please have a look